# Definitions: max, min, sup and inf of a sequence

Tags: calculus

I find it hard knowing the difference between the supremum of a series and and the infimum

So we have

$\sup(a_n)$ and $\inf(a_n)$

what does it signify when we say a series has a maximum but not a minimum  or has both maximum and minimum etc?

- For example

$$a_n = 1 + 1/n$$

we know that the series is bounded by $1≤a_n≤2$, I know that it has a max which is 2 but
how come we say it doesn't have a minimum

Comment: Because $a_{n+1} < a_n$ for all $n$, so there is no smallest element in the sequence. $\inf \{a_n\} = 1$ is not an element of the set $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$.

Comment: You probably mean sequence and not series.

Comment: what the author means is that the minumun is not "in the set" $\{a_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. we know that minimum value is 1, but for no $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n=1$.

Comment: what I don't understand is  what do you mean by an 1 is not an  element of the set?

Comment: I pardon for my wordings, I assumed you are not so familiar with difference between infimum and minimum, so i thought i should first use what you know already and then rephrase it precisely. what i mentioned in last comment is actually infimum. By very definition minimum of a set is an element in the set..... whereas infimum of an set need not be in the set...

Comment: i mean that, for no $n\in \mathbb{N}$ i can get $a_n=1$. i.e., what ever $n\in \mathbb{N}$ i substitute, i will not get $1+\frac{1}{n}=1$.

Comment: @franck Try to get in the habit of accepting *one* helpful answer per question asked. (Bonus: you get 2 points when you accept a question). To accept an answer, simply click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It turns *green* after clicking on it once. Very soon you'll be able to *upvote* as many helpful answers as you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

The set $[0, 1]$ contains all of the numbers between $0$ and $1$ including $0$ and $1$. Therefore, it has maximum element $1$ and minimum element $0$.

The set $[0, 1)$ contains all of the numbers between $0$ and $1$ including $0$ but *not including* $1$. Therefore, it has no maximum element, as if $m$ was the maximum element then $m<1$ and so $\frac{1+m}{2}\in[0, 1)$. However, $m<\frac{1+m}{2}<1$, which contradicts the maximality of $m$. But *clearly* this set has a "biggest element" (namely $1$), the twist is that this element isn't actually in the set. So we give this "maximum if it was in the set" element a name, "the supremum", and give it a formal definition (the least element greater than or equal to all elements of $[0, 1)$, or whichever set you are working with).

The concept of infimum is analogous, and this can all be applied to your specific example.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum is infimum when infimum is an element of the set, here infimum is 1 but 1 is not an element of the set $a(n)=1+1/n$ so it is not a minimum. Same for maximum and supremum.